# How to sort records by pagewise

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am using a grid to display records. Consider that I am having 75 records in Data Table. And I am displaying 25 records per page. In this I have to sort the records on Second page using a specific column. Is it possible to sort the records in particular page? Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you talking about ordering page2 results only while being on that page or are you talking about ordering all results and displaying page2 when someone orders results?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in the normal case. Can be achieved in a complicated manner. You have to copy the 25 records for a page to a new datatable and then apply the sort criteria to the newly created datatable.

Either you can sort the whole datatable or fetch 25 records at a time from database and sort them based on a particular column.

In the first method make a dataview of the datatable and apply the sort criteria to the dataview. In this case the whole records will be sorted.

In the second approach you can fetch 25 records each time a page is changed and keep those records in a dataview and apply the sort criteria.

Comment: Retrieve the page set and then apply your sort filter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding some some sort of client based sorting functionality, a good one is jQuery + the plugin [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). This way you handle paging server side and handle sorting client side.